# MVC5 Using Controller to serve images, value can not be null

Tags: asp.net, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC and I followed another tutorial on loading local files to the webpage and while it seems to work for others I am getting an error.

```
public class ImagesController : Controller
{
    // GET: Images
    public ActionResult SomeImage(string imageName)
    {
        var root = @"C:\Images\";
        var path = Path.Combine(root, imageName);
        path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        if (!path.StartsWith(root))
        {
            // Ensure that we are serving file only inside the root folder
            // and block requests outside like "../web.config"
            throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
        }

        return File(path, "image/png");
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

`An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code`
`Additional information: Value cannot be null.`

And the line it highlights is:

`var path = Path.Combine(root, imageName);`

Comment: Is `imageName` null?

Comment: Clearly `root` isn't null. Therefore `imageName` must be null. Have you verified what the value of `imageName` is?

Comment: imageName is whatever I set it to in my view so I currently I'm using: `<img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Action("SomeImage", "Images", new { image = "Logo.png" })" alt="" />`

Comment: You need `new { imageName = "Logo.png" }` instead

Comment: @haim770 Ah, rookie mistake thank you for that. If you create it as an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Also, your current approach *may* block unwanted files from being downloaded, but it does expose whether certain file or directory exists in the server (and that includes even paths like `c:\boot.ini`). An attacker can obtain lots of useful information from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Url.Action()` helper, the property name in the anonymous object has to match the name of the parameter in the action.

And in your case:

```
@Url.Action("SomeImage", "Images", new { imageName = "Logo.png" })
```

Answer (score 1):

As [haim770](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625737/haim77) mentioned, it looks like you are missing the "Name" part of the imageName parameter.  You can certainly add error handling to your code in order to localize the exception.  This might help you narrow down any coding issues.

```
if(imageName == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(null, "imageName is NULL");
}
```

Comment: I would use method String.IsNullOrEmpty :)

Comment: Good point.  I use that all the time and I didn't write it.  My bad!